# Autofac with quartz

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac, quartz.net

I am trying to use Quartz in my ASP.NET MVC App.

I want to use DI in quartz and for web api controllers.
I have such Global.asax:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().AsSelf().WithParameter("connectionString", Resources.ConnectionString);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var container = builder.Build();

        var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(delegate(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServerService>().As<IServerService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServerDataService>().As<IServerDataService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<SiteDataService>().As<ISiteDataService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<SiteService>().As<ISiteService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<MembershipService>().As<IMembershipService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<CriteriaService>().As<ICriteriaService>();

            containerBuilder.Register(e => new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler()).As<IScheduler>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .Where(e => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(e));
        }
            );

        CustomDependencyResolver.SetContainer(scope);

        var webScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(delegate(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
                .As<IUnitOfWork>()
                .As<IRepositoryFactory>()
                .InstancePerApiRequest()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServerService>().As<IServerService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServerDataService>().As<IServerDataService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<SiteDataService>().As<ISiteDataService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<SiteService>().As<ISiteService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<MembershipService>().As<IMembershipService>();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<CriteriaService>().As<ICriteriaService>();
        }
            );

        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(webScope);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

        var sched = scope.Resolve<IScheduler>();
        sched.JobFactory = new AutofacJobScheduler(scope);
        sched.Start();

        //sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        var job2 = JobBuilder.Create<HJob>().WithIdentity("job2").Build();
        var trigger2 =
            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger2")
                .StartNow()
                //.WithSimpleSchedule(e => e.WithIntervalInSeconds(15).RepeatForever())
                .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job2, trigger2);
```

And I have my HJob class:

```
public class HJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (var container = CustomDependencyResolver.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var serverService = container.Resolve<IServerService>(); // This line!
            var siteService = container.Resolve<ISiteService>();

            serverService.CreateServer(DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But on the line where I brought comment my job stopped and getting out of function Execute.

What can be wrong with this?
Thank you.

CustomDependecyResolver class:

```
public static class CustomDependencyResolver
{
    public static ILifetimeScope Container { get; private set; }

    public static void SetContainer(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }
}
```

AutofacJobScheduler class:

```
public class AutofacJobScheduler : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;

    public AutofacJobScheduler(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob) _container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? I don't see any error handling, so I'm guessing that you get an exception while resolving `IServerService`, maybe because some dependency is not registered? Try stepping through the code and check if some exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I have found a solution. But cuz I am new user.    I can't answer my question during 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an issue.
There is no good idea for two lifetime scopes of container in Global.asax.
I found those solution.
Create one scope and then set them to CustomDependencyResolver.

And refactor HJob class:

```
public class HJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (var container = CustomDependencyResolver.Container.BeginLifetimeScope(
            builder => builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().As<IRepositoryFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            ))
        {

        }
    }
}
```